# How to Set a MXD to Open With the Data Always 'Paused'? ArcMap 10.3.1?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.3

I have several MXDs with large datasets (some with over a million features). I would like to open the MXD with the data in a 'paused' state, rather than having the MXD open and draw every feature; since this takes way to long. If I open the MXD, then try to 'pause' the drawing of the features sometimes this works immediately and the data pauses drawing, other times this attempt takes way too long.

I have to keep the layer in the MXD always on, since later the MXD will be used to create a mapping service.

Is there a setting where I can set the MXD to always open as 'paused'?

This is what I would like my MXD to look like when I open.

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1.

[image]

Comment: I doubt there's any way to generate a pause event automatically on open. It would be better to make the dense feature class scale-dependent, so that it doesn't render at inappropriate scales.

Comment: @Vince These MXDs with their associated data will eventually be published as cached mapping services. For this reason I have not set scale dependency. The reason I would like them to open in a paused state, is so that I can make an necessary symbology, label, etc. changes needed, that will be reflected in the mapping service.

Comment: If you're doing cached mapping services correctly, they *will* be scale dependent, so it doesn't take weeks to generate the upper levels of the cache.

Comment: @Vince My services take up to 45 mins max for my largest dataset, 3.5 millions features to cache the service, so this is not an issue for me. My issues is opening an MXD, which takes too long when ArcMap attempts to draw all features, some MXDs also have specialized drawing order, which takes even long. My goal is to have the option to open an MXD in a paused state.

Comment: Yeah, but I can't see how that would be possible.  If you can't make the MXD scale dependent, maybe you could zoom the starting map extent so it doesn't try to render all features.

Comment: Could you run a Python script to open your map document and then use the SendKeys module to send F9 to pause drawing right away?

Comment: If you save them with layout mode open and draft, next time it will open without redraw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked around this in the past by setting the Data Frame in Draft Mode (*Data Frame Properties > Frame > check Draft Mode*) then going into Layout View (*View > Layout View*) before saving my MXD. This reduces the drawing time significantly.

For example, I had 3 million points and 500,000+ lines saved in a MXD. I followed the instructions above, saved the MXD and closed out of it then re-opened it. It only took 22 secs for the project to open completely vs the 1 minute wait if not in Draft Mode and in Data View.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done if you have VBA installed and licensed. The following lines of code pause the display on an *on open document event*. As the code is in the normal template it gets executed for every MXD you open. Then its up to you to turn on display.

*...then wished never did it!* :)

[image: VBA editor]

Code for copying:

```vb
Private Function MxDocument_OpenDocument() As Boolean
    Dim pMXApp As IMxApplication2
    Set pMXApp = Application
    pMXApp.PauseDrawing = True
End Function
```

Comment: Can you copy and paste the code into your answer as well?